# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler Dozer

Tags: spring, maven, dozer

I'm using Dozer 5.4.0 with Spring 3.2.4 and Maven.

I try to configure Dozer via XML in this way:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">



</mappings>
```

But when I deploy my app I obtain this:

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'mappings' of schema namespace 'http://
 dozer.sourceforge.net'
```

In my pom.xml I insert the correct reference:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

why?

Comment: How do you load your dozer xml file in your spring context ?

Comment: Hi, the dozer configuration is inside a xml file in the contextConfigLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same problem. Issue is because I haven t placed my mappings.xml (Dozer Mapping) file in src/main/resources path where maven will use its dependency to resolve the namespace. And placing the file in the build path (src/main/resources) resolved my issue.

Thanks,
Prasanna.